# Finding Laplace transform of piecewise function $f(t)$

Tags: laplace-transform

$$f(t) = \begin{cases} t , & 0 \leq t < 1 \\ 2 - t, & t \geq 1 \end{cases}$$ then $f(t) = t + (2-2t)\mathscr{U}(t-1)$ so $\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} = \mathcal{L}\{t\} + \mathcal{L}\{(2-2t)\mathscr{U}(t-1)\}$

I got $\displaystyle \frac{1}{s^2} + \left(\frac{2}{s} - \frac{2}{s^2}\right)e^{-s}$ which would be right if not for the $\dfrac{2}{s}$ term but I don't know how it's not supposed to be there.

Comment: Thee transform of $g(t-a)U(t-a)$ is $e^{-as}G(s)$. What is $g(t)$?

Comment: @Paul Oh.. so $g(t) = t$ and it should be $g(t-2)\mathscr{U}(t-1)$ and in the alternative form $\mathcal{L}\{g(t)\mathscr{U}(t-a)\} = e^{-as}\mathcal{L}\{g(t+a)\}$

Comment: wait i wrote that wrong should be $\mathcal{L}\{(-2(t-1))\mathscr{U}(t-1)\} = \frac{-2e^{-s}}{s^2}$

Comment: $$\mathcal{L}_t[f(t)](s)=\frac{1-2 e^{-s}}{s^2}$$